# Assign a separate ID to each div JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment

I use this code to wrap every 3 divs in a seprate div and this works:

```
$('.a_paj_element:nth-child(3n)').each(function(index) {
    $(this).prevAll('.a_paj_element').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="three_paj_els" style="display:none;" />');
});
$('#paj_container > .a_paj_element').wrapAll('<div class="three_paj_els" style="display:none;" />');
```

I Have been trying how to assign each wrapping div its own ID in numeric order kind of like this:

```
<div id="1" class="three_paj_els" style="display:none;" ></div>
<div id="2" class="three_paj_els" style="display:none;" ></div>
<div id="3" class="three_paj_els" style="display:none;" ></div>
```

Like it Auto Increments. each ID it makes. When i try and do it I can't get it to increment.

How do I do this if it's possible?
Thanks a bunch
-sal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
var ID = 0;
$('div.three_paj_els').each(function() {
    ID++;
    $(this).attr('id', 'id'+ID);
});
```

I'm not sure whether numbers alone are valid IDs.

Comment: OHHH that makes so much sense! Thank you!