# Dynamically cloned elements with jquery - can't .remove() them or increment their ID's

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, append, clone

I'm making a user input form initially containing 1 info 'pod' with 2 inputs. There is an 'Add Another' button to dynamically duplicate the pod multiple times via clone()/insertBefore() - this seems to be working ok. Here's a fiddle of what i've done so far: http://jsfiddle.net/N6Xty/8/

It's getting messy with the following two features: 
1: I need a 'Remove Me' button (ie remove-self) only in the cloned pod elements, not the original pod - this is only slightly working and I tried 2 approaches, firstly with .removeClass(), second with an 'if' statement (which is commented out) but the 'if' throws a console syntax error that I can't rectify. 
It's far easier to view the Fiddle than to explain what's happening, but the 1st 'Remove' button is on the wrong pod, and this is the only one that actually works ... For code reference there are 2 related variables: 'removeThisDivButton' and 'removeThisDivButton02'

2: Each cloned pod has form input elements - I want them to have unique ID's (e.g. for labels to reference textarea) so I've been trying to implement dynamic id incrementing with limited success, and I'm also trying for unique id's on the actual pods (not 100% req but I'd like it ideally). For this there are 2 'append ID' scripts, one which utilises 'index' and one commented out which I got from this SO post: [Append ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757749/assign-a-separate-id-to-each-div-jquery)

(I've seen other 'append id' replies but I don't understand how to apply them to this).

If anyone can advise me on any of this then huge thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="outer-wrapper">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <a href="#" title="Duplicate" class="duplicate-butt">Add Another</a>
            <form name="userInfoForm" method="post" action="">
                <div id="info-div-" class="append-me-div">      
                    <select name="various-options">
                        <option>-- Please Choose --</option>
                        <option value="opt-one">One</option>
                        <option value="opt-two">Two</option>
                        <option value="opt-three">Three</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="message-">Comments:</label>
                    <textarea id="message-" class="message-box" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>

                    <a href="#" class="remove-this-div hidden-button">Remove ME</a>

                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
(function($){
        // append ID (partly working)
        $('#info-div-, #message-').each(function(index){
            $(this).attr({
                'id': this.id + index
            });
        });

        // duplicate the <div>append-me-div</div> + show the 'Remove Me' button
        var duplicateButton = $('a.duplicate-butt');
        var appendMeDiv = $('div.append-me-div');
        var removeThisDivButton = $('a.remove-this-div');
        //var removeThisDivButton02 = $('<a href="#" class="remove-this-div">Remove ME</a>');

        duplicateButton.on('click', function(index){
            appendMeDiv.clone().insertBefore('button#submit-button');

            // 'Remove Me' version01
            removeThisDivButton.removeClass('hidden-button');   

            // 'Remove Me' version02
            /*if (this.appendMeDiv:eq+=(1)){
                removeThisDivButton02.appendTo(this.appendMeDiv);
            }*/

            // append ID (PARTLY working)
            /*appendMeDiv.attr({
                'id': this.id += 1
            });*/

            // append ID (not working)
            var idIncrement = 0;
            $('#info-div-, #message-').each(function(){
            //$('#info-div-').each(function(){
                idIncrement++;
                $('this').attr('id', 'id'+idIncrement);
            });

            console.log('a.duplicate-butt clicked');
        });

        // remove the current/parent <div>append-me-div</div>
        removeThisDivButton.on('click', function(e){
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            e.preventDefault(); // tried this to stop the page auto-scrolling back to top on click - not working
            console.log('CLICKED: a.remove-this-div');      
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: It might just be easier to use a small template so that you have more control...

Comment: You need to store a reference to the clone and act on the clone rather than the original element.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I can see the sense in this so I made anew fiddle here: [http://jsfiddle.net/JTKBq/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/JTKBq/2/)
I'm attempting the template route, storing this as a variable and referencing that variable - my console reports `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal` so that's pretty clear. 
Can someone please look at the new fiddle and advise me how to make this template properly. Thanks

Comment: You can't put all those hard returns in there. This doesn't give the error (but still doesn't work). http://jsfiddle.net/JTKBq/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going. You have to store your new clone as an object, then do your operations on that. This will surely need some tweaking, but hopefully it'll get you rolling.

http://jsfiddle.net/N6Xty/9/

All the magic happens here: `var newOne = appendMeDiv.clone();`. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks @Tim Wasson !!! much appreciated and I can see straight away what you've done there, a bit help.
I tried adding one extra bit though - I wanted to increment the 'for' attribute of the labels to be in line with textareas so I used your logic and tweaked the fiddle thus: `newOne.find(".comments-label").attr("for"+idIncrement);`
Doesn't work though, can you advise?

Comment: Looks like you mis-formatted a bit. It'll be something like `newOne.find(".comments-label").attr("for","for-"+idIncrement);`

Comment: Silly me - I just added the extra param to .attr() and all's fine: `newOne.find(".message-label").attr("for","message-id-"+idIncrement);`

Thanks again, a big help on the learning curve

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very simple, the knack being to attach the handler to the *original* "Remove me" button then using `clone(true, true)` to clone everything including the attached handler :

```
(function($) {
    var appendMeDiv = $('.append-me-div');
    var submitButton = $('#submit-button');
    var count = 0;
    $('.remove-this-div').hide().on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.append-me-div').remove();
    });
    $('a.duplicate-butt').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clone = appendMeDiv.clone(true, true).insertBefore(submitButton).find('.remove-this-div').show().end();
        var messageBox = clone.find('.message-box');
        var id = messageBox.attr('id') + ++count;
        messageBox.attr( 'id', id ).prev('label').attr( 'for', id );
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DDy5W/)**

Personally, I would omit the `<label for="...">` functionality. It's not particularly important in this case as the textarea is a much larger target than the label.

The javascript would reduce to :

```
(function($) {
    var appendMeDiv = $('.append-me-div');
    var submitButton = $('#submit-button');
    $('.remove-this-div').hide().on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.append-me-div').remove();
    });
    $('a.duplicate-butt').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        appendMeDiv.clone(true, true).insertBefore(submitButton).find('.remove-this-div').show();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ycA3n/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Beetroot, again a huge help. I'm looking at and learning from both of these solutions.
With this example I'm tinkering a little to get the id of `#append-me-div` to auto increment; so far tried `var $messageBox = clone.find('.append-me-div, .message-box');` but no good so will continue tinkering.

Comment: Ids with an incremental suffix are typically unnecessary, though it took me about 15 years of writing javascript to discover this. The only case I'm aware of where incrementals (or something similar)  can't be avoided is with `<label for="...">`, which you currently have, but can probably do without as I already suggested. If you can explain to me why `#append-me-div` currently needs an increment, then I'll see if I can help. If the explanation gets complex, then ask a separate question and post a link here.

Comment: It's not 100% needed (i did mention this in the post) but has been covered in Tim Wasson's solution and i was able to apply this to `label for="..."`. However i am very happy to know this technique as it can have other apps. Thanks for your input though!